# Getting "The table didn't load correctly" in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

I'm trying to create my first excel data driven app. 
I created a Workbook in Excel 365, put some data and inserted a Table on top of it.

When I select that workbook via Power Apps, it's unable to load the table.

The Excel is in OneDrive for Business and I'm using the same account.

The OneDrive is not being synced to my computer.

[image: Power Apps Error]

[image: Excel Table]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've used an Excel file as a PowerApps DataSource, it was a local file (not Excel O365). You might try downloading a copy of the file locally, then connecting it to PowerApps.

If you want a cloud-hosted Excel file:

1. Save the file to OneDrive then View/DataSource and add the OneDrive Connector to your app

[image]

2. Select the Excel file then the Table to use

[image]

Just a heads up, Excel-based DataSources, especially those hosted in OneDrive can be quite finicky. There are file locks and sync issues that can make things challenging.

I'd recommend only using this type of setup for testing OR use a local Excel file for static data that rarely changes.

Move to Sharepoint as an intermediate DataSource, and finally to a formal database as a best practice.

Comment: I'm using OneDrive for business. Edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.

Just try to delete/disconnect and reconnect your OneDrive for business from the Power App.

To delete the connection.

1. Go to Power App
2. At the left hand side, click at 'Data' > 'Connections' menu
3. Delete all of your OneDrive

Try to connect it again, it should work fine.